# Share buttons on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, social-networking

I've been trying to make the share buttons to appear when hovering on an article "Mashable style" but I can't seem to get it right. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div class="c-container">
    <article class="c-news">
        <header> 
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://a_really_long_url.jpg" 
                    alt="post-image" class="post-image">
            </a>
        </header>
```

look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJRtm/)

Comment: Your span does not have any dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `:hover` CSS selector:

- First hide the elements:

  ```
  .st_facebook_hcount, .st_twitter_hcount {
    position:relative;
    display:none; /* Hide It*/
    width:6rem;
    top: -1.2rem;
    left:18rem;
  }
  ```
- Then set the `:hover` to show:

  ```
  .c-news:hover .st_facebook_hcount, .c-news:hover .st_twitter_hcount {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  ```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/nJRtm/6/**